# javascript ArrayBuffer, what's it for?

Tags: javascript

Maybe it's late, or maybe it's the sake, but I just read the docs for [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) and can't think of a single thing it would be really useful for.

Can someone enlighten me?

Are there any uses anyone can think of that don't involve images?

Comment: Hmmm, seems like node.js would love this for low level IO related code.

Comment: From unconscious memory I remember that such things are used to keep binary data (like binary data of an image) to manipulate and store/send it. Plus if you work on application program then you can know buffers are very useful. And HTML 5 is now gone beyond web programming....

Comment: I guess @Imdad is right. The HTML5 canvas context has a method `getImageData` which returns many properties of the drawn image, including one called `buffer` of the type `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: A small use is described @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Basically ArrayBuffer is used to keep binary data. It can be the binary data of an image for example.

In other languages buffers are proved very useful. Yes, of course it is a little more difficult to understand/use than other data types.

ArrayBuffer can be used to get data of jpg image (RGB bytes) and produce a png out of it by adding alpha byte (i.e. RGBA).

Mozilla site has given a small use of ArrayBuffer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Working_with_complex_data_structures)

> ### Working with complex data structures
>
> By combining a single buffer with multiple views of different types,
> starting at different offsets into the buffer, you can interact with
> data objects containing multiple data types. This lets you, for
> example, interact with complex data structures from [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL), data files,
> or C structures you need to use while using [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes).
>
> Consider this C structure:
>
> ```
> struct someStruct {  
>   unsigned long id;  
>   char username[16];  
>   float amountDue;  
> };
> ```
>
> You can access a buffer containing data in this format like this:
>
> ```
> var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(24);  
>   
> // ... read the data into the buffer ...  
>   
> var idView = new Uint32Array(buffer, 0, 1);  
> var usernameView = new Uint8Array(buffer, 4, 16);  
> var amountDueView = new Float32Array(buffer, 20, 1);
> ```
>
> Then you can access, for example, the amount due with
> `amountDueView[0]`.
>
> > **Note:** The [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) in a C structure is
> > platform-dependent. Take precautions and considerations for these
> > padding differences.

Comment: So can one assume that an ArrayBuffer is unnecessary if you already know you are working with e.g. pure unsigned 8 bit data, you might as well create a Uint8Array and fill that? What about Blob and FileReader - they seem to work on ArrayBuffer? At least thats how I normally work on binary files in javascript.

Comment: Refer to the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: Idview should take 4 bytes not 1

Comment: idea is that length parameter is number of elements, not bytes, judging by the example. try ```new Int32Array(Uint8Array.from([1,2,3,4]).buffer,0,1)``` to test it.

Comment: This really doesn't add much to the answer besides providing a copy-paste from the Mozilla site.

Answer (score 10):

An [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) is a chunk of binary data in RAM. There are a few ways to "open" an `ArrayBuffer` for reading and writing:

- [Typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), such as `Uint16Array`, can read and write the buffer by treating it as an array of integers. They don't let you control [endianness](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/bytes/latest/Bytes#Endianness); it uses the CPU's preferred endianness. `Uint8Array` is useful for controlling individual bytes (copying, slicing, etc).
- [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) is not as simple, but it gives you more control. It lets you choose the endianness, integer size, and byte index (e.g. you can access a 32 bit integer at an index that's not divisible by 32 bits). These things can be specified each time you read and write an integer with the same `DataView`.

More info: https://javascript.info/arraybuffer-binary-arrays

Answer (score 9):

Other than images, it's useful for precisely constructing and destructing low level network data packets used in protocols like UDP.