# Cannot get the value of an ArrayBuffer Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, arraybuffer

I have an `ArrayBuffer` object that I need to be able to convert to `String` to `JSON`, but I can't get the value of the `[Int8Array]` out of the object, even though it is clearly there.

[image]

I've tried all variations on this, but they all return undefined

```
console.log(result);//Returns the array buffer
//Following methods all return undefined?
console.log(result["[[Int8Array]]"]);
console.log(result[[[Int8Array]]]);
console.log(result[[["Int8Array"]]]);
console.log(result[Int8Array]);
console.log(result["Int8Array"]);
```

How can I get all the Int8Array or UInt8Array values that are clearly available in the object?

Comment: You should be able to get the individual values using `console.log(result[0])` etc.

Comment: That did not work, also always returns undefined. The comment below is correct in that I needed to instantiate a new ArrayBuffer for the values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11555049/5734311

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to intiantiate a `new Uint8Array` to get their values, you can't access them directly using your `ArrayBuffer` instance.

```js
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var int8view = new Uint8Array(buf);
console.log(int8view)
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v8m7pjqb/

Answer (score 8):

You can use the textDecoder that accepts ArrayBuffer (as well as uint8array) without having to deal with Uint8array's:

```
var str = new TextDecoder().decode(arrayBuffer)
var json = JSON.parse(str)
```

if you want to get straight to json

```
var json = await new Response(arrayBuffer).json()
```