# How can I parse a UDP packet using a c header file in node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm trying to connect a server that reads Telemtry Data from a racing simulator.

I have been researching on how to listen for the UDP packet and have so far successfully be able to listen to the client and receive the packets and then log the ArrayBuffer.

I've come across this StackOvervflow answer that shows how to parse it

[javascript ArrayBuffer, what's it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554006/javascript-arraybuffer-whats-it-for)

I was wondering however if there is any other way of parsing the C++ Header File in an automatic manner or if I have to sanitize the data myself

Here's a sample of my express node.js server

```
server.on("message", (buffer, rinfo) =>{
    console.log("received udp message")
    console.log(buffer)
})
```

Here's a sample of the c++ header file

```
enum EUDPStreamerPacketHandlerType
{
    eCarPhysics = 0,
    eRaceDefinition = 1,
    eParticipants = 2,
    eTimings = 3,
    eGameState = 4,
    eWeatherState = 5, // not sent at the moment, information can be found in the game state packet
    eVehicleNames = 6, //not sent at the moment
    eTimeStats = 7,
    eParticipantVehicleNames = 8
};
```

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction, my google searches haven't turned into much, any help would be appreciated

Comment: A C++ header file is just a bunch of constant/variable/class declarations. You will need to figure out how the data in the header file is used in the actual code that reads the messages.

Comment: So basically all I need to do is manually parse the data?

Comment: If the original code does not use a general purpose deserialization library, yes. Take a look at [kaitai struct](http://kaitai.io/) to describe the data structures and generate an efficient Javascript parser.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the python code

https://github.com/tyretrack/server/blob/91a0aba1ade8d3a45b53e5af432fb05a55703730/tyretrack/pcars/v2.py

It would be up to you to convert it to your desired javascript code.